# Is a three hour in house interview that mostly covers work history standard?

Tags: interviewing

Yesterday, I had an in-house interview with two engineers and then later the owner of the company. It lasted three hours. Not sure what to make of a three hour interview about just work history and aspirations. Is that standard?

Comment: What does "in-house" mean in this context? As in "on the premises of the new company"? Or "applying to a different job with the same company"?

Comment: @Erik, on the premises of the new company.

Comment: I don't know what "In house" means but I had a total 8 hour interview before. 4 hours with 3 managers (IT) and another 4 hour with 3 different managers (Financials). There isn't a standard. Every job/company is different

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no standard. Different companies have different hiring practices. Some focus on personal interviews, some on your on-paper qualifications, some focus on standardized tests. Also, companies tend to invest more time into hiring decisions when it's about a more important position. You wouldn't spend as much time on picking a janitor as you would on picking a branch manager. So depending on the job and the company, job interviews can take anywhere between a few minutes to several hours.

But when an interview takes longer, that's usually a good sign. It means everyone is interested in you. When they would have found some reason to not hire you early, they would have cut the interview short and gotten back to their actual work, not needlessly waste your and their time by extending the interview.

Comment: That makes sense, I guess the team are excellent at playing poker because I could not assess what such a long interview meant. I used to be good at telling whether I got the job or not or whether they were interested or not.

Comment: @dwizum I bowed to peer pressure and changed the answer.

Comment: @Philipp upvote added.

Comment: I challenge the notion that janitors are less important than branch managers... ever work in a building with no custodians? Yeah. Certainly janitors' job skills are in greater supply, But less important? You can run a  business for a week with no manager on site. Try it without a janitor. Enjoy the plummeting morale from the overflowing trash and filthy bathrooms.

Comment: @Adonalsium I did not claim that you don't need a janitor, just that the decision which janitor to hire is not nearly as important as the decision which manager to hire.

Comment: Even setting aside what it means for you personally, a long interview that mostly focused on things you've already done means that someone there took the time to actually pull up the research on what works and what doesn't in the interview process, and that's a rare thing. I'd say it speaks well of the company itself.

Comment: @Philipp You said managers are more important. I am contesting your use of language.

Comment: I work in a company without janitors. Been here nearly five years, so far no overflowing trash nor filthy bathrooms. But, we are all adults... maybe it's different if you work with children.

Answer (score 5):

At my current job, the interview was rather long.
I spent 30 minutes with the recruiter, then 30 minutes with the manager I would report to,  then just over an hour with the team i would be joining, then a little more than an hour with the IT directory (above the manager).  Then 10-15 minutes with team and manager.  Then we all went out to lunch.  We only spoke of personal interests during lunch.  Then back to the office where i spent another 30 minutes or so with the manager.

Comment: This is a pretty typical of how many tech jobs hire in the US.  Great answer.

Answer (score 4):

Your (pre-edit) question was,

> Is that standard?

It's hard to answer what is *standard* for interviews because policies will vary from position to position and industry to industry. That said, a 3-hour interview is certainly not *unusual* for many positions, and the structure you experienced (team technical interview, followed by a one on one interview with a leader) is pretty standard for a longer interview.

Comment: You edited out the rest of your question as I was typing my answer so I'll leave the rest of my answer out - although you seemed stuck on their interest in your history so maybe that's worth a separate question.

Comment: Yes, I edited it out, because I started to see one close vote, so I thought that it needed to be edited.

Comment: I thought it raised a good point, you seem concerned about how to address your consulting/freelancing history in an interview setting, or at least concerned about how your history is being perceived. You might get some good feedback about how to address those concerns if you create a new question focused on that.

Comment: I agree with you. It is an issue I would like addressed. I will create a new question regarding my consulting/freelancing history.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a standard. Shortest interview I had didn't even last 10 minutes (I did get the job), longest I had was 7 hours: twelve 30-minute interviews with peers, followed by a one hour interview by the manager. And I've had everything in between as well.

At my current job, if you get to the stage of face to face interviews (we start off with phone interviews and coding tests), the candidate starts off with 30 minutes with a recruiter (mostly about the process of hiring/relocation), then has 2 one hour interviews with 2 peers (so 4 peers in total), followed by a 30 minute interview from someone from management. And then they see the recruiter again.

From my (limited) experience, both as a candidate, an interviewer, and from talking about others about hiring processes, I'd say that 3 hours is far from unusual.